# C# P2P: peer's data and comment aren't set

Tags: c#, p2p

I'm trying to insert data in a peer, but it doesn't work.

I leave below the code that I'm using:

```
PeerNameRegistration pnReg = new PeerNameRegistration();
pnReg.PeerName = peerName;
pnReg.Start();
pnReg.Port = 80;
pnReg.Comment = txtName.Text;
pnReg.Data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Data");
pnReg.Stop(); (?)
```

When I check the peers, I can see 4 nodes, but none of them has data or comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify proprties' values before calling the `Start()` method. If you want to change a property's value after the registration of peer, you can use `Update()` method.